# SQL regex to check if within JSON array there exists at least one item

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table in MySQL 5.6 with a text type field "custom_info" which exists JSON as string. Such a JSON's exist field "clients" with array.

In order to select records where "clients" is empty I use query:

```
select custom_info from users where custom_info like '%"clients":[]%'
```

How could I retrieve records where "clients" array exist at least one element?

Comment: Try `where custom_info REGEXP '"clients":\\[[^]]'`

Comment: Seems like it works! You could write it as a separate answer so that I could mark it as a solution. Thank you!

Comment: If your `mysql` is new enough, there are functions that reach into JSON.  Use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to only return entries having no `]`  after `"clients":[` you may use

```
where custom_info REGEXP '"clients":\\[[^]]'
```

The `\\[` is actually a `\[` pattern matching a literal `[` char, and `[^]]` is a negated bracket expression matching any char butr a `]`.

Comment: I noticed that option provided by George Pant found more records for some reason, trying to understand the difference

Comment: Your case found exactly the records I expected, thank you, marked as solution, would appreciate if you voted my question

Answer (score 5):

MySQL natively supports JSON. Instead of storing as a string literal, I recommend storing it as a [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html). In doing so, it will open up several native functions like [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html), [JSON_ARRAY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html), and [JSON_OBJECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html).

You could then use [JSON_CONTAINS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) or [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) to evaluate your results; something like:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   custom_info
WHERE  JSON_CONTAINS(clients, 'some_value_youd_expect_to_be_here')
```

Or:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   custom_info
WHERE  JSON_EXTRACT('clients', '$[0]') is not null
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response! Unfortunately I can't change type of field so that I try to parse it

Answer (score 1):

In the case you want to keep your field as text type you could use `_%` which will match at least one character

```
select custom_info from users where custom_info like '%"clients":[_%]%'
```

Comment: I've found that your case includes records with '"clients":[]', so seems like case of Wiktor Stribiżew works more precisely

Comment: This version works only in case you have not other arrays after "clients" in your json like the example you provided.In case you have other arrays after "clients" inside the json it will not work since _% will match at least one character ( that includes ] ) and the last ] will be matched by the other array....